# Setting button width with fx:Style

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, adobe, mxml

I have 4 buttons, all of them have the same width.

```
<s:Button id="btn1" width="{btnWidth}" />
<s:Button id="btn2" width="{btnWidth}" />
<s:Button id="btn3" width="{btnWidth}" />
<s:Button id="btn4" width="{btnWidth}" />
```

Is it possible to set their width with `Style`, something like this:

```
s|Button{
   width: btnWidth;
}
```

I tried it, but auto-complete isn't working, which leads me to think that there's something wrong with the syntax. Basically my goal is to not have the `width` property set specifically for all 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't work out of the box because width is a property of button, not a style. You can only specify styles in your stylesheet.

However, what you can do is extending Button and add a style that controls the width of your button.